# In Bayesian statistics, how do I compare proportions between multiple subgroups with weighted data?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, bayesian, proportion

I have the following data in `R`:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = 2012:2016, 
                 Sub_A = c(221.0317, 310.5392, 247.7214, 184.7109, 243.2550),
                 Sub_B = c(276.4308, 322.6342, 227.5891, 184.3510, 188.2100),
                 Sub_C = c(127.01029, 99.89520, 70.19430, 73.02120, 76.79611),
                 Sub_D = c(443.7368, 411.5475, 346.2134, 390.3476, 375.8736),
                 Sub_E = c(236.0558, 258.3134, 199.3459, 164.9189, 222.2181),
                 Sub_F = c(615.1197, 591.3498, 482.6987, 450.9629, 400.5997),
                 Total = c(1253.000, 1339.751, 1033.000, 1051.000, 1148.000))
```

Within the Bayesian framework, I'd like to compare for each subgroup whether there is a significant difference from year to year in its proportions, which can be established by the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, Sub_A_prop = Sub_A / Total,
           Sub_B_prop = Sub_B / Total,
           Sub_C_prop = Sub_C / Total,
           Sub_D_prop = Sub_D / Total,
           Sub_E_prop = Sub_E / Total,
           Sub_F_prop = Sub_F / Total)
```

A vague beta-binomial prior distribution would be fine. How do I go about doing so in `R`?